# When I make a text file in Xcode, how can I access it?

Tags: ios, swift, file, xcode8

In Xcode, I did File > New > File... > Empty. I named this file `NameList.txt`, and it appears in the sidebar on the left along with all of my `.swift` files and the main storyboard. In this file, I have stored over 200 that I need inside my program. I have a class that can read from a text file line-by-line and store each line in a `String` array, but I cannot locate this file. I always have an empty array that throws an "Index out of bounds" error when I try to pull a name, even the 0th index. I do not know how to access my file.

I used the following code as the pointer to where the file should be (from other articles here on StackOverflow and YouTube):

```
let fileName = "NameList"
let DocumentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("txt")
```

This does not work. I have tried several solutions, but none have worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you all in advance!

Comment: It's stored in your app's bundle.  You can get the url with: `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "NameList", withExtension: "txt")`

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for.